# Java Read file and match with current time

Tags: java, file, metatag

I have this tag

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="Thu, 23 Aug 2012 09:30:00 GMT">
```

in the file. I have to find this tag in file and get the content part out of it and match with the current date and time.
If date and time in the file is older than current time set a flag. Can somebody help me to do this, I am new to this? Thanks

Comment: I just know how to read a whole file in java after that what i am suppose to do get just that tag

Comment: or is there a better way to parse it and read it

Comment: @user1617247 the better way to parse HTML to use the libraries meant to parse HTML (like I mentioned in my response). The solution you have accepted as the answer looks simple but can lead to issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here might help you getting started:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindStringInFileTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File f = new File("c:/test.txt");
        String res = find(f);

        if (res != null) {
            System.out.println("Found Meta Http-Equiv tag");
            System.out.println(res);//print META HTTP-EQUIV line
            //check the line for whatver dates etc here
        } else {
            System.out.println("Couldnt find Meta Http-Equiv tag");
        }

    }

    public static String find(File f) {
        String result = "";
        Scanner in = null;
        try {
            in = new Scanner(new FileReader(f));
            while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                String tmp = in.nextLine();
                if (containsMetaHttpEquiv(tmp)) {
                    result = tmp;//assign line which has META HTTP-EQUIV tag
                    break;//so we dont check more
                } else {
                    result = null;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static boolean containsMetaHttpEquiv(String str) {
        if (str.contains("<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Expires\" CONTENT=")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

It will read in the text file and check for `META HTTP-EQUIV` tag and either return the line/string which contains the tag or `null` if no `META HTTP-EQUIV` tag could be found.
you would then extract the date using `substring()` and `indexOf()` methods and then parse this to a `SimpleDateFormat` and then compare the 2 dates, and write flag appropriate flag to file.

EDIT:

Here is the method needed to extract the content from the HTTP-EQUIV META tag:

```
public static String getContentOfMetaTag(String tag) {
    String search = "CONTENT=";
    return tag.substring(tag.indexOf("CONTENT=") + search.length() + 1, tag.indexOf('>') - 1);
}
```

you would call this method with the `String` returned from `find(new File)` (make sure its not null before calling `getContentOfMetaTag(String tag)`)

Comment: What if the META tag is on multiple lines?

Comment: NOT really! Parsing html files without the corresponding library leads to issues like this. Yours is a naive solution.

Comment: @Pangea I find it ridiculous to use libraries for something that can be done in pure java. So yes you are correct, but I'm not the type to depend on libraries. call me independent

Answer (score 2):

1. The content file seems like an HTML file. So use a library like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) to retrieve the value of the CONTENT attribute of META tag.
2. Then use `SimpleDateFormat` to convert the string to a `Calendar`/`Date` object.
3. Then use [`after()`/`before()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) API for comparison.